# Took shahada secretly

Tags: shahada

I secretly took shahada recently. From then on, I've been praying namaz and reading qur'an sincerely. My parents don't know about this. I'm hiding my faith.

I always avoid [pooja](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puja_(Hinduism)) (a Hindu form of worship to idols) at home. They doubted me a few times. Yesterday there was pooja. My mother had periods so she told me to do that. I denied her so she doubted me. So I had to do pooja, but I didn't recite the [aarti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aarti) (Hindu songs of worship). I didn't do it properly.

What should I do now?  I asked Allah for forgiveness also. Should I take shahada again?

Comment: What is Pooja and what is aarti?

Comment: The point of the *shahada* is that it is a public proclamation of faith. If this is in secret, are you worried about Islamophobia?

Answer (score 1):

This question is between you and Allah. You do not need to re-take shahada as your inner intention was Islam the whole time while you had to perform such practices.

I would highly suggest talking to a local Imam about your situation.

Answer (score -2):

I congratulate you on your entering Islam, the religion of truth and of sound human nature with which Allah created His slaves. I ask Allah, may He be glorified, to make you steadfast in adhering to His religion and to protect you from the evil of the devils among mankind and the jinn. I ask Allah to make the life easy for you.

With regard to your disbelieving parents, you have to honour them, uphold ties with them, and keep company with them on a basis of kindness and at the same time keep away from shirk. Allah, may He be exalted, says (interpretation of the meaning):

“And We have enjoined on man (to be dutiful and good) to his parents. His mother bore him in weakness and hardship upon weakness and hardship, and his weaning is in two years give thanks to Me and to your parents, unto Me is the final destination.

But if they (both) strive with you to make you join in worship with Me others that of which you have no knowledge, then obey them not, but behave with them in the world kindly, and follow the path of him who turns to Me in repentance and in obedience. Then to Me will be your return, and I shall tell you what you used to do.”

[Luqmaan 31:14,15]

As Allah said "repentance" is the key. So always ask Allah for forgiveness. Try to talk with your parents, respect them and show them that you became a very good and respectful person. So they will understand you and accept you when they found out about you that you accepted Islam. May Allah make things easy for you.

[Source 1](https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/220070)